# SQL 2000 query trouble

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000, pivot

consider the following table

```
create table sample(id, name, numeric, qno, ans1,ans2,ans3)

sample data

1, 'vivek', 1, 'a', 'b', ''
2, 'vivek', 1, 'c', 'd', ''
3, 'vivek', 2, 'e', 'f', 'g'
4, 'vivek', 3, 'h', 'i', 'j'
5, 'vijay', 1, 'k', '', 'l'
6, 'vijay', 2, 'm', '', 'n'
7, 'vijay', 2, 'o', '', 'p'
8, 'vikram', 3, 'q', 'r', 's'


output expected

column Names: name, info1, info2, info3

    values
'vivek','ab','ef','hij'
'vivek','cd','',''
'vijay','kl', 'mn',''
'vijay','','op',''
'vikram','','','qrs'
```

converting rows into columns.

in other words. one answer will have one row. there can be multiple answers to one question.

the output should have answer numbers as columns.

is there any quick and easy technique in sql 2000?

Comment: Whats the criteria? For instance, why is abc,abc missed out?

Comment: sorry for the confusion. i edited the question.

Comment: @Vivek - The question and expected answer still dont make clear sense. Can you review your question properly and edit it.

Comment: the structure of the table and the values are correct. the requirement is to produce a csv file with answers as columns. but in the table each question will have a one row. the number of lines in the output will be equal to the max number of answers for a question. for example: if qno1 has 10 answers, qno2 has 2 and qno 3 has 8 answers. the total number of rows in the output will be 10.

Comment: the number of columns in table sample (7 cols) doesn't match your sample data (6 cols). Besides that, it is very difficult to infer the logic behind the expected output - please describe what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: At first I thought they were asking for a CROSSTAB query but the expected results do not match that type of output.

Comment: let me edit the structure and sample input and output more clearly

Comment: I think, Vivek wants smth. like to group by name and numeric and grouping all columns ans1, ans2, ans3 which have same name and numeric in one string.

Comment: @Vivek, both before and after your edits there are multiple rows in your expected output for the same name and numeric values - eg. Sample row IDs 1 and 2. Please can you explain the logic used to derive your expected output?

Comment: here's the application logic. it's an application with a 3 questions. there can be 0 to n number of answers to any question. the questions are stored in a table like the sample table i posted. we are expected to create a module where users can download all the answers in that format.

Comment: @Vivek: I don't understand the transformation used to get from the sample data to the expected output.  Could you please edit the question to describe this transformation in detail?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, if I understand your problem, then I think your first result should be 
'vivek','ab','efg','hij'  rather than 'vivek','ab','ef','hij'

If so, then I think the following **may** do what you want.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TempDB..#TempSample') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #TempSample

DECLARE @PrevName  nvarchar(80),
@PrevRow_number     INT,
@PrevQno int 


select
    isNull(id, 0)   as id , 
    isNull(sname, '')   as sName , 
    IsNull(qno,0)       as qno ,
    ans1, 
    ans2, 
    ans3  , 
    CAST(0 AS INT) AS row_number ,
    Cast('' as Nvarchar(80)) as newAns1, 
    Cast('' as Nvarchar(80)) as newAns2, 
    Cast('' as Nvarchar(80)) as newAns3
    INTO #TempSample
    from 
    (select id, sname, qno, ans1, ans2, ans3 from sample ) t3


ALTER TABLE #TempSample ADD PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (sName, qno , id)

UPDATE #TempSample 
    SET @PrevRow_number = row_number = CASE WHEN   sName = @PrevName and qno = @PrevQno THEN @PrevRow_number +1 ELSE 1 END,
        @PrevName  = sname ,
        @PrevQno   = qno,
        newAns1                        = case when sName = @PrevName and qno=1 Then newAns1 + ans1+ans2+ans3 else newAns1 end ,
        newAns2                        = case when sName = @PrevName and qno=2 Then newAns2 + ans1+ans2+ans3 else newAns2 end ,
        newAns3                        = case when sName = @PrevName and qno=3 Then newAns3 + ans1+ans2+ans3 else newAns3 end 
FROM #TempSample  WITH(TABLOCKX)
OPTION (MAXDOP 1)


Select sName,  Max(newAns1) as Ans1 , Max(newAns2) as Ans2, Max(newAns3) as Ans3 
From #TempSample 
Group by sName, Row_Number
Order By sName
```

Had a similar problem with Sql 2000 recently, so credit must go to [this article](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic854349-149-1.aspx) on SqlServerCentral

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no simple way to create a pivot in sql 2000.